# Jackson same value for two different attributes

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

In a Spring 1.4.5 application I receive data in a Controller with:

```
@PostMapping(value = ENDPOINT, consumes= "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<?> post(@RequestBody Email email) {
```

Where Email has an attribute

```
@JsonPropery(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
@Email
private String mail;
```

The Controller receives a mail (I checked with an Interceptor) but it is not picked in the Controller due to the *READ_ONLY* that I do not dare to remove (it's been in production for years).

I tried to duplicate *mail* with a new attribute

```
@JsonPropery("mail")
private String from;
```

but I get *JsonMappingException Conflicting getter definitions for property*

How can I pick the mail existing in the incoming json?

Comment: as per docs `READ_ONLY` -> `Access setting that means that the property may only be read for serialization, but not written (set) during deserialization.` you should be able to access that property after serialization

Comment: within the post method, the property is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that has worked has been not creating a getter for the new propery:

```
@JsonPropery(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
@Email
private String mail;

@JsonPropery("mail")
private String from;

private String getMail() {
   return mail;
}
private void setMail(String mail){
   this.mail = mail;
}

private String calcFrom() {
   return from;
}
private void setFrom(String from) {
   this.from = from;
}
```